# Event Webform Templates?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I have a complex Event registration process, for which I create a complex Webform (I use Webform Integration).

This event recurs several times a year, and the webform is painful to re-create each time.

Is there any way to either clone an existing webform (then adapt), or create a Event Webform template from which I could then derive individual Event Webform occurrences ?

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a Drupal answer than a CiviCRM answer, but I believe you can use [Node Clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) to copy/duplicate webforms.

> The clone module allows users to make a copy of an existing item of site content (a node) and then edit that copy. The authorship is set to the current user, the menu and url aliases are reset, and the words "Clone of" are inserted into the title to remind you that you are not editing the original content.

Comment: Agreed.  That's how we do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, Laryn and Allen : I did not know this Module.

Comment: Agreed. Using this as well!